# get hash from strings, like hashids

Tags: node.js, hash, hashids

Using the package [hashids](https://github.com/ivanakimov/hashids.node.js), I can obtain hashes (with encode and decode) from numbers.

```js
    var Hashids = require("hashids"),
        hashids = new Hashids("this is my salt", 8);
    
    var id = hashids.encode(1);
```

Is there a similar package to obtain hashes from strings?
(with encode and decode)

Answer (score 37):

```
var Hashids = require("hashids");
var hashids = new Hashids("this is my salt");

var hex = Buffer.from('Hello World', 'utf8').toString('hex');
console.log (hex); // '48656c6c6f20576f726c64'

var encoded = hashids.encodeHex(hex);
console.log (encoded); // 'rZ4pPgYxegCarB3eXbg'

var decodedHex = hashids.decodeHex('rZ4pPgYxegCarB3eXbg');
console.log (decodedHex); // '48656c6c6f20576f726c64'

var string = Buffer.from('48656c6c6f20576f726c64', 'hex').toString('utf8');
console.log (string); // 'Hello World'
```

Comment: Buffer? Where can I find it? Thanks!

Comment: Client-side? Browser...:)

Comment: @Eusthace
Buffer is part of Node.js core api - https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end
You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/buffer for browser support

Answer (score 1):

Getting hex without Node's Buffer.from ( to use with hashids.decodeHex)

```
const toHex = (str: string): string => str.split("")
        .reduce((hex, c) => hex += c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).padStart(2, "0"), "")
const toUTF8 = (num: string): string =>
        num.match(/.{1,2}/g)
            .reduce((acc, char) => acc + String.fromCharCode(parseInt(char, 16)),"");
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a quick implementation for [sqids.js](https://sqids.org) (formerly hashids), using code from [hashids.encodeHex](https://github.com/niieani/hashids.js/blob/master/src/hashids.ts#L180) method and includes the buffer toString hex workaround from @roman-rhrn-nesterov [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27137224/350598):

```
function convertStringToNumbers(input) {
    const hex = Buffer.from(input).toString('hex');
    return Array.from({ length: Math.ceil(hex.length / 12) }, (_, i) => Number.parseInt(`1${hex.slice(i * 12, (i + 1) * 12)}`, 16));
}

const sqids = new Sqids()
const id = sqids.encode( convertStringToNumbers( 'any string' ) );
```

**!** This code does not provide a decode method, you have to adapt [decodeHex()](https://github.com/niieani/hashids.js/blob/master/src/hashids.ts#L186) for that part.